# Angular 2 - How to render child component first

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have the following scenario:

```
<router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>

<div class="content-wrapper">    
      <router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>

      <div class="content">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
</div>
```

I realized that "router outlet sidebar" content is loaded/rendered after

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
```

And I'm facing some layout issues with that. Is that possible to load it before?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't that there's a way of specifying rendering order. What layout issues are you encountering?

Comment: @Harangue sidebar is being rendered over content (which is inside div content wrapper) while it should be rendering on content left side. When I put fixed html template instead of router, it works perfect. So I realized it is being rendered after div content wrapper.

Comment: That sounds more like a CSS issue than anything. Can you create a plunkr with your code?

Comment: @Harangue It's a lot of code and files to post there. But let me try: I'm using the following template: [link](http://demo.interface.club/limitless/layout_1/LTR/default/index.html) Take a look and you'll see sidebar fits perfectly on the left side. In my case, I'm loading the sidebar in a router and apparently it is loading after router siblings (in this case <div class="content-wrapper">) and header is being rendered under sidebar. Did you get it? Tks.